# Shifting split text array

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue to shift a split text array

```
let text = "Hello world";

console.log(text.split(" ").shift()) // Hello
```

It gives me `Hello` instead of `world`

Comment: Hi @connexo, sorry I didn't read it properly. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `Array.prototype.shift()` function removes the first element of the array as expected AND returns it. That is the reason why you get "Hello". To get "world", you should do `text.split(" ")[1]`.

Have a great day, Lukas Laudrain.

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Hi Lukas. Thanks for the reply. I already viewed the reference link you gave and found the way to solve my issue. Thanks